# Converting XML to HTML based on complex elements in the input xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am new to XSLT, I am trying to parse the data in below xml to html, wherein each root/Quote/Quotes is a Vehicle, the value of Vehicle is determined based on QuoteId in the respective quote, I need to display the corresponding values of Quote-1 & Quote-2 with QuoteID under 1st `<Sequence>` & 2nd `<Sequence>` side-by-side based on QuoteID, I need to display all the distinct elements in all the root/Quotes/Quote with the value of it, or if the any of element or element's value is not present - I need to display 'Not Found'

It is possible that first `<Sequence>` can have root/Quotes/Quote's with `<SequenceID>`'s 1, 2, 3 and 2nd `<Sequence>` can have `<SequenceID>`'s 1 & 3, in which case I need to display all the label values of Quote-2 as 'Not Found'

**Input XML**

```
<HTMLData>
    <Sequence>
        <QuoteTitle>Quote-1</QuoteTitle>
        <Response>
            <root>
                <Quotes>
                    <Quote>
                        <Element1 value="122"/>
                        <Element2 value="233"/>
                        <Element3 value="344"/>
                        <Element4 value="455"/>
                        <QuoteID value="1"/>
                    </Quote>
                </Quotes>
                <Quotes>
                    <Quote>
                        <Element1 value="466"/>
                        <Element2 value="577"/>
                        <Element7 value="688"/>
                        <Element8 value="799"/>
                        <QuoteID value="2"/>
                    </Quote>
                </Quotes>
            </root>
        </Response>
    </Sequence>
    <Sequence>
        <QuoteTitle>Quote-2</QuoteTitle>
        <Response>
            <root>
                <Quotes>
                    <Quote>
                        <Element1 value="233"/>
                        <Element10 value=""/>
                        <Element11 value=""/>
                        <Element12 value="123"/>
                        <QuoteID value="1"/>
                    </Quote>
                </Quotes>
                <Quotes>
                    <Quote>
                        <Element13 value="123"/>
                        <Element14 value="234"/>
                        <Element15 value="456"/>
                        <QuoteID value="2"/>
                        <Element16 value="654"/>
                    </Quote>
                </Quotes>
                <Quotes>
                    <Quote>
                        <Element13 value="234"/>
                        <Element14 value="443"/>
                        <Element15 value="654"/>
                        <Element16 value="544"/>
                        <QuoteID value="3"/>
                    </Quote>
                </Quotes>
            </root>
        </Response>
    </Sequence>
</HTMLData>
```

**Desired Output**

```html
<table xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" border="1">
 <tr>
  <th class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Type</th>
  <th class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Vehicle</th>
  <th class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Label</th>
  <th class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Quote-1</th>
  <th class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Quote-2</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Motor</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Vehicle1</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element1</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">122</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">233</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element2</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">233</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element3</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">344</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element4</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">455</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">QuoteID</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">1</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element7</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element8</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element10</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element11</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element12</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">123</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element13</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element14</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element15</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element16</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right" colspan="count()">Motor</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Vehicle2</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element1</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">466</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element2</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">577</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element3</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element4</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">QuoteID</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">2</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element7</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">688</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element8</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">799</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element10</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element11</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element12</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element13</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">133</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element14</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">234</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element15</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">456</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element16</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">654</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right" colspan="count()">Motor</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Vehicle3</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element1</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element2</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element3</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element4</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">QuoteID</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element7</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element8</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element10</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element11</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element12</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element13</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">234</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element14</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">443</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element15</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">654</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Element16</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Not Found</td>
  <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">544</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. There is no <SequenceID> in your input. And it's difficult to understand the mapping of the input to the output - esp. when some of the values are not unique.

Comment: Sorry I mean QuoteID, I need all the names of elements to be present in all the Vehicles with value if the value is present, if not, value should be 'Not Found'

Comment: Each <Sequence> represents a transaction (named as <QuoteTitle> value), and each Quotes/Quote represents a Quote under that transaction, my requirement is to display the values of <Quote>'s having same <QuoteID> under different <Sequence>'s side-by-side in HTML.                                                                                               Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are converting rows in the input to columns in the output, and you are looking for elements which might not be included in each `<Quote>`.

To manage this, you need a list of all possible element-names and the maximum number of `<Quotes>`.

Then you can loop through the list of `Quotes` by `position()` and look for all elements from the `$elements` list.

Complete solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:key name="element-key" match="//root/Quotes/Quote/*" use="name()" />

    <!-- collect all posible element-names -->
    <xsl:variable name="elements">
        <xsl:for-each select="//root/Quotes/Quote/*">
            <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('element-key', name())[1])">
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="elements" select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="Quote/*" mode="elements">
        <element>
            <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:attribute>
        </element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="vehicleCount">
        <xsl:call-template name="vehicleCount">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodelist" select="//root"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template name="vehicleCount">
        <xsl:param name="nodelist" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count($nodelist) > 0">
                <xsl:variable name="countFirst" select="count(exsl:node-set($nodelist[1])/Quotes)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="maxRest">
                    <xsl:call-template name="vehicleCount">
                        <xsl:with-param name="nodelist" select="exsl:node-set($nodelist[position()>1])" />
                    </xsl:call-template> 
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$countFirst > $maxRest"><xsl:value-of select="$countFirst"/></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$maxRest"/></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="quoteTitles">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/HTMLData/Sequence/QuoteTitle"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="sequences">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/HTMLData/Sequence"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Type</th>
                <th class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Vehicle</th>
                <th class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Label</th>
                <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($quoteTitles)/*">
                    <th class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:call-template name="outputVehicle"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="outputVehicle">
        <xsl:param name="pos">1</xsl:param>

        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($elements)/*">
            <xsl:variable name="elementName" select="@name"/>
            <tr>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$elementName = exsl:node-set($elements)/*[1]/@name">
                        <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Motor</td>
                        <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">Vehicle<xsl:value-of select="$pos"/></td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
                        <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"></td>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right"><xsl:value-of select="$elementName"/></td>
                <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($quoteTitles)/*">
                    <xsl:variable name="quoteTitle" select="text()"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="quote" select="exsl:node-set($sequences)/*[QuoteTitle=$quoteTitle]/Response/root/Quotes[position()=$pos]/Quote/*[name()=$elementName]/@value" />
                    <td class="border-top border-bottom border-left border-right">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$quote"><xsl:value-of select="$quote"/></xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>Not Found</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </td>            
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>        
        </xsl:for-each>


        <xsl:if test="$pos &lt; $vehicleCount">
            <!-- wonder if xslt-processors are able to do tail-call optimization... -->
            <xsl:call-template name="outputVehicle"><xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos+1" /></xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I am supposed to use xslt 2.0, I could get the list of complete nodes & count using distinct-values() & count(), I am currently stuck up at displaying the values, can someone please help me with the complete solution.

Comment: You can still use the same two templates (match="/" and name="outputVehicle"). However, xslt 2.0 also has support for grouping which might make it simpler.

Comment: And this solution will still work with a xslt-2.0 transformer.

Comment: Thanks Rolf for the response, I have worked out the solution with 2 xslt's. I will tune this to XSLT 2.0 for my need. Thanks again!!